# ActionScript 3: how to get the class by just having the name

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i am trying te recieve the class with only having the name of the class so example:

```
var className:String = "TheClass";
var theClass = new className();
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to use [flash.utils.getDefinitionByName](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform//reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName()) for it and supply the full qualified name.  Try this:

```
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

var cls:Class = getDefinitionByName("com.domain.project.TheClass") as Class;
var instance:Object = new cls();
```